# IIS not allowed on company computer

Tags: software

I am working on a company to do web development. And some feature that I am requested to do requires IIS (IIS Express from VS does not seem to have it all). But I can not have IIS active on my laptop.
This is the first company of this type and I did not received a valid/satisfactory answer why.

So what might the reason(s) be?

EDIT
Maybe I did not formulate the question in order to understand me. 
So when I asked my manager he said the IT department told him that the IIS is banned from the developers computers. But since the discussion was years before my arrival to the company he could not give me a reason. Of course there are servers where the IIS is installed. And ofcourse I do not have access to those.

So I would like to know are there really threaths in having the IIS on the developer machine?

Comment: When you asked them how to complete the feature without IIS, what did they say?

Comment: If every developer wants to use their own development tools or whatever, you don't think that will cause a problem if you want any of those people to work on the same code? Also, how do you manage security when you allow anyone to install whatever they want? Also, the more constructive response to "You can't have X" is "How do I do this without X", not "Why can't I have X".

Comment: One reason might be that they don't want the application to be dependent on IIS. As soon as you add features that are IIS-specific, everyone who hosts that application will have to install that same server, which might not be practical. Ask yourself if the feature really can only be implemented by installing a specific server. More likely is that it can be implemented without it, perhaps with more development effort (which you will need to explain as part of your time estimate).

Comment: You write IIS is required for your work but you can't have it on your laptop. Where can you have it (where is it installed) if not on your laptop? It must be somewhere, otherwise you can't do that job.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue several years ago. They did not ban full IIS, but having a local administrator account which is required to be able to set up and debug IIS deployed applications.

Fortunately, the company had an internal flow that allow getting a local administrator account: fill a designated document, send to the user services (+ cc to manager), wait for a while.

The most important part was to correctly indicate the reasons that required local administrator account. Theoretically, IIS Express should be fine, but some functionalities work differently (some library crashed on a colleague's development environment because of non-local admin / IIS Express usage).

My suggestions are as follows:

1. Try to find out why you are not allowed to have IIS locally.
2. Clearly state that some features cannot be developed without a full IIS. Stick to the facts and emphasize that some deliveries can be impacted if this is the case. It is important for your manager (or product owner) to know about this as soon as possible.
3. If you do not find a way, ask for a more isolated environment (e.g. a VM) where you have full rights (install IIS, publish against it etc.)

Answer (score 0):

IT departments love one-size-fits-all solutions. In a perfect world everyone in the company would have the exact same computer with the exact same software in the exact same configuration. That would make their job orders of magnitude easier. The less software they have the less security vulnerabilities they need to worry about, the less incompatibility problems they need to take care of and the more they can automatize. So anyone who comes around and says "but I really want to use software X instead of software Y" throws a wrench into their gears.

Usually there will be a process in place how you can request an unique software for your work, but it will be intentionally convoluted to make sure you only use that process when you really **must** have that software and don't just want to satisfy your personal preference.

Ask your manager about what you need to do when you need a specific software for your job. Don't ask for IIS, ask for a description of the general process. You will then have a better understanding of what your request actually entails. That will make it easier for you to argue and provide the necessary paperwork for your manager so they just need to forward it to the right recipient.